# Quickly switch back to in-progress call or navigation?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-maps-navigation, navigation

One of my favorite iOS features is that, when you have a call or turn-by-turn navigation in progress and switch apps, you can easily return just by tapping the status bar.

In android, I've noticed a number of apps that can show floating widgets over other apps - Facebook messenger's floating "chat heads" and CyanogenMod's floating calculator widget are good examples.

Is there any way to make similar floating icons appear when on a call or when navigating in the background, that when tapped will quickly return to the relevant app?

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.4 on Samsung Note 4, while you are using an app, phone calls will pop up as a small moveable window on top of that current running android app. You can maximise/minimize that moveable window. This might be a better solution to multitasking while having a phone call on the same device. I am not sure cyanogenmod have the similar features, though.

However, stock Android 4.4, have a pull down notifications window. Applications such as Google Maps Directions and Waze, will put a notification icon in the notifications status bar while you are navigating, so pulling down the notifications window will allow you easy access to switch back to the navigation application. As [the screenshots](https://plus.google.com/118059448416645829809/posts/UAG9Xknbmf7) shows the notification window have resume navigation bar at constant place in the middle of the screen, on top of other notifications.

Comment: Yes, I know I can get back to a phone call or navigation from the notifications window. That's sill a little inconvenient though. (Especially while driving, I don't want to have to look away from the road to browse through the busy, complicated notifications list looking for Google Maps.) I was hoping for something even easier, like the moveable window you're talking about. (That's what facebook messenger does too, except the "window" is by default just a single, small, fairly unobtrusive circle - very convenient.)

Comment: I added screenshots of the notifications window. It has the resume navigation button at constant place in the middle of the screen.